# Custom MessageBox

Tags: c#

I want to create a custom messagebox 
but i want use the custom icons and custom sound in during show messagebox
how do I create this Messagebox??
I no want to use the shell32.dll and user32.dll

a messagebox the same as windows 7 for windows xp

Comment: What exactly do you want to customize?

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way would be to create your own MessageBox window from scratch. If you are looking for hooks to default windows MessageBox you need to consider that later you can run into problems like compatibility with other Windows operating systems.

Here are couple of samples how to create your own MessageBox:

- [Creating A Custom Message Box](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19711/Creating-A-Custom-Message-Box-Part)
- [A Custom Message Box](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17253/A-Custom-Message-Box)
- [Custom Message Box](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16389/Custom-Message-Box)

That will give you an idea about logic and how to start writing your own custom MessageBox.

Comment: Your second link is also dead

Answer (score 3):

I used a simple dialog with a static method **ShowCustomButtonsDialog**. I placed a text label in the top left corner and changed border style to Dialog. Method simply returns button index or -1.

```
public partial class CustomButtonsDialog : Form
{
    private const int ButtonHeight = 24;
    private const int ButtonPadding = 6;
    private const int ButtonInnerPadding = 5;
    private const int MaxFormWidth = 700;

    private int buttonIndex = -1;

    public int ButtonIndex
    {
        get { return buttonIndex; }
        private set { buttonIndex = value; }
    }

    public static int ShowCustomButtonsDialog(string text, string title, params string[] buttonsText)
    {
        var dlg = new CustomButtonsDialog(text, title, buttonsText.ToList());
        dlg.ShowDialog();
        return dlg.ButtonIndex;
    }

    public static int ShowCustomButtonsDialog(string text, string title, List<string> buttonsText)
    {
        var dlg = new CustomButtonsDialog(text, title, buttonsText);
        dlg.ShowDialog();
        return dlg.ButtonIndex;
    }

    public CustomButtonsDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private CustomButtonsDialog(string text, string title, List<string> buttonsText)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Text = title;
        labelText.Text = text;

        // добавить кнопки
        var formWidth = ClientSize.Width;
        List<int> buttonWidths;            
        using (var gr = CreateGraphics())
        {
            buttonWidths = buttonsText.Select(b => (int)gr.MeasureString(b, Font).Width + 2 * ButtonInnerPadding).ToList();                
        }
        var totalButtonWd = buttonWidths.Sum() + (buttonWidths.Count - 1) * ButtonPadding;
        if (totalButtonWd > formWidth)
        {
            if (totalButtonWd <= MaxFormWidth)
                Width = Width - ClientSize.Width + totalButtonWd + ButtonPadding * 2;
            else
            {// trim some buttons
                Width = Width - ClientSize.Width + MaxFormWidth;
                totalButtonWd = ClientSize.Width - ButtonPadding * 2;
                var avgWidth = (totalButtonWd - (buttonsText.Count - 1) * ButtonPadding) / buttonsText.Count;

                var sumThins = buttonWidths.Sum(w => w <= avgWidth ? w : 0);
                var countThins = buttonWidths.Count(w => w <= avgWidth);
                var countFat = buttonsText.Count - countThins;
                var spareRoom = totalButtonWd - sumThins;
                var fatWidth = (countThins == 0) || (countFat == 0)
                                   ? avgWidth
                                   : (spareRoom - (countThins - 1)*ButtonPadding)/countFat;
                for (var i = 0; i < buttonWidths.Count; i++)
                    if (buttonWidths[i] > avgWidth) buttonWidths[i] = fatWidth;                    
            }
        }
        // buttons' Y-coords and height
        labelText.MaximumSize = new Size(totalButtonWd,
            labelText.MaximumSize.Height);
        var buttonTop = labelText.Bottom + ButtonPadding;
        var formHeight = buttonTop + ButtonHeight + ButtonPadding;
        Height = Height - ClientSize.Height + formHeight;

        // do make buttons
        var buttonLeft = ButtonPadding;
        var tag = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < buttonWidths.Count; i++)
        {
            var button = new Button
                             {
                                 Parent = this,
                                 Width = buttonWidths[i],
                                 Height = ButtonHeight,
                                 Left = buttonLeft,
                                 Top = buttonTop,
                                 Text = buttonsText[i],
                                 Tag = tag++
                             };
            button.Click += ButtonClick;
            buttonLeft = button.Right + ButtonPadding;
            Controls.Add(button);
        }
    }

    private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonIndex = (int) ((Button) sender).Tag;
        Close();
    }
}
```